# How do I use keys from a dynamic JSON to create javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON string in format
`[{"DATE":"2019-01-01","A":0,"B":0}]`
generated by a php script where there can be any number of keys with different key names and values.

What I am trying to do is access these key names when creating a js array.

This is easy when I know what the key names are:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "data.php",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
  let date = [];
  let one = [];
  let two = [];             

  for(let i in data) {
    date.push(data[i].DATE);
    one.push(data[i].A);
    two.push(data[i].B);            
  }
...
```

I just push them into array by key name. But what if I don't know the key names beforehand (DATE, A and B in this example)?

I tried getting the key names and using them instead of static 'DATE', 'A' and 'B', which doesn't work. Example:

```
const x = Object.keys(data[0]);
console.log(x[1]);
```

This results in 'A', but I can't use it as `one.push(data[i].x[1]);` to populate an array. The error in console is

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined".

I am searching for a solution and would appreciate your help understanding this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encase the entire `x[1]` in square brackets to use it as the key - otherwise, you're trying to access the first item in `data[i].x` which doesn't exist:

```
one.push(data[i][x[1]]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Jack, I understand it now.

Comment: No problem @Ante, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```js
let a = [];
let b = [];
let c = [];

const data = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}];

data.forEach( function(item, index) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(i, ind) {
     eval(i+'.push('+item[i]+')');
  })
});
  
console.log('a is=', a, 'b is =', b, 'c is =', c);
```

Comment: Don't use `eval` unless it's completely necessary - in this case, it's not.

Comment: Yes i know @JackBashford. but this i did for him.. if he has more key, he suppose to create empty based on additional keys..

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track but syntax was incorrect. You will have to use data[i][x[1]] instead. In your example "data" has no "x" attribute so it was causing error.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed solved my problem.